# Calling new activity from an item inside a recyclerview row

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, startactivityforresult

I need to call a new activity, when a button inside one of my recyclerview row elements is called. Each row item in the list contains 4 buttons, one of which needs to open a new activity which will be used to edit the data in that row.

Here is the code for my button so far:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CounterLayoutAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final 
    int position) {
    final Counter counter = counterList.get(position);
    //counter is a class which holds the data that will be displayed on one 
    //row

    String comment = counter.getComment();
    String name = counter.getCounterName();
    int number = counter.getCurrentValue();
    //LocalDate modifyDate = counter.getLastModifyDate();

    Button up = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUp);
    Button down = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDown);
    Button reset = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonReset);
    Button edit = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEdit);
    Button delete = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

 //  code for 4 other buttons goes here
 //
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
```

Since I need the activity that I open to return user inputted data for me, I am using startActivityForResult. However, as far as I can tell, this will only work inside an actual activity class.

So then I tried passing the mainactivity context to my CounterLayoutAdapter class, where all of my button code is. However, the OnBindViewHolder method still cannot access it there. So I tried to pass the context to OnBindViewHolder, but that doesn't work either, as it won't override the abstract class if i do that..

So, how on earth can I call a new activity here?

Alternatively, if there is some other way to get user input into 4 fields and return that input back to the adapter, without calling an activity, that would work as well.

EDIT:  viewholder and layout inflation

```
   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
   View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView name;
        private TextView comment;
        private TextView number;
        //private TextView date;



        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textComment);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextNum);
            //date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {}
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflatedView = 
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout
        .row_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(inflatedView);
    }
```

Comment: are you inflating any layout?

Comment: yes, I am inflating  my layout, i added that code to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `startActivityForResult()` in adapter class.

- Get context in adapter like `Context context=holder.up.getContext();`
- then in your button's OnClickListener do this.

  ```
  edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent intent=new Intent(context,ActivityYouWantToStart.class);
          //Pass any extras if you want to.
          ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
      }
  });
  ```
- Then in your activity (which contain this recyclerView) override `onActivityResult` like this

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {//same REQUEST_CODE you used in adapter

           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

              //Do your thing and get the data you want.

             adapter.onDataReady(Data data);//where adapter is your recycler adapter, 
                                            //and data is whatever data you want to pass to adapter 
                                            //(Data you got from the activityResult, do not confuse it with onActivityResult's parameter 'Intent data') 
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally in your Recycler Adapter class, define `onDataReady()` function like

  ```
  public void onDataReady(Data data){
     //Update RecyclerView with new data
  }
  ```

Hope this helps. I once did this, and it works for me. Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: your method of obtaining the context didn't work, but the onDataReady function solved my issue anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As you see , you do not have to `findViewById` in `onBindViewHolder`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CounterLayoutAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final 
int position) {
final Counter counter = counterList.get(position);
//counter is a class which holds the data that will be displayed on one 
//row

String comment = counter.getComment();
String name = counter.getCounterName();
int number = counter.getCurrentValue();
//LocalDate modifyDate = counter.getLastModifyDate();


holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
});
```

Then you should init `edit` in `ViewHolder` constructor.

```
   public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textComment);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextNum);
        //date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        // init four button
        edit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEdit)

    }
```